how to access amazon secret manager from nginx.conf for react.js google search indexing
I have a website www.jermasearch.com that I can trying to give good search engine optimization so it shows up in google searches, and displays a nice preview card when the link is shared on social media. After doing some research it seems like this is more tricky than I thought, but one solution is to use prerender.io which solves SEO by serving prerendered HTML to Google and other search engines.
After starting to go through the pretender.io setup guide, I chose the nginx way, since my website is hosted in AWS using the ECS containers with docker and nginx.conf. But this requires the use of a MY_TOKEN secret inside the nginx.conf file:

With having my nginx.conf hosted publicly on github, I can't hardcode the TOKEN value obviously, so is there anyway I can set this secret inside my nginx.conf file using an env var secret provided by AWS? Here is my nginx.conf currently:
https://github.com/MartinBarker/aws-react-docker-ghactions/blob/main/nginx.conf
And If I follow the pretender.io instructions, my nginx.conf would have this TOKEN string which needs to be contain my secret:
    location /prerenderio {
      if ($prerender = 0) {
          return 404;
      }

      proxy_set_header X-Prerender-Token YOUR_TOKEN;  // token here
      proxy_set_header X-Prerender-Int-Type Nginx;

      proxy_hide_header Cache-Control;

In a different file, server.js, I get a secret from the AWS Secret Manager using this code:
const { GetSecretValueCommand, SecretsManagerClient } = require("@aws-sdk/client-secrets-manager");
...
async function getAwsSecret(secretName) {
  try {
    const awsClient = new SecretsManagerClient({ region: "us-west-2" });
    const response = await awsClient.send(
      new GetSecretValueCommand({
        SecretId: secretName,
      }),
    );
    return response.SecretString;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error getting aws secret: ${error}`);
    throw error;
  }
}


Is there a way I can add similar code to my nginx.conf file to retreive a secret from AWS? Or do I need to try a different method? Thanks

Don't have an exact answer but you can probably mount the nginx.conf from a Docker secret, so it isn't stored in the container.
